# Table isn't found due to case-sensitivity MySQL query using .NET MySQL Connector

Tags: mysql, asp.net, .net, mysql-connector, mysql-5.7

I am using an old website that I've created using .NET 4.0 with XSD (Table Adapters). I've migrated my database from MySQL 5.4 to MySQL 5.7 on AWS RDS.

The problem that I have is that when I run the website, it can't find the table because in some of the queries it searches for a table with a capital letters in the beginning. If I change the table name to with capital letter, it finds it. It's an old project, and I prefer not messing around with the old code.

I use .NET MySQL Connector.

```
show variables where Variable_name='lower_case_table_names'
```

The above returns '0' which means 'lettercase specified in the CREATE TABLE or CREATE DATABASE statement. Name comparisons are case sensitive.'

Is there a way to update the web.config or do something in the MySQL database to make it work so the query will count as case insensitive?

Comment: Did your MySQL database begin its life hosted on Windows, then get migrated to RDS?  It probably did, because that OS has case-insensitive identifiers.

Comment: Did you switch between Windows and non-Windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with like
where Variable_name like 'lower_case_table_names

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL 5.7 on RDS has not value for the lower_case_table_names in the GROUP PARAMETERS in RDS configuration panel. Once I set it to 1 and rebooted the server, my old .NET website worked properly.